# Change ImageIcon object transparency (alpha)

Tags: java, transparency, panels

My aim is to have multiple panels with images that have alpha channels (transparent parts) on top of each other. So I followed the code in this site http://tinyurl.com/m27exs. It worked the way I wanted it. It had two `ImagePanel` objects on top of each other with the top-most having an alpha channel (transparent part).

Now my problem is how I can change the transparency (see-throughness?) of the `ImageIcon` objects inside that `ImagePanel` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Darryl's [Alpha Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/08/22/alpha-icons/).